# HTML5 Canvas - Block side collisions on dynamic map

Tags: javascript, canvas, collision

I'm making a platformer game in HTML5 Canvas and I have run into some collision problems. I've been experimenting with numerous collision algorithms but I can't seem to get any to work.

---

My question:
How can I get the blocks/darker grey squares to stop my ball from passing through it?

---

Some info about my code:

- The map is dynamically generated
- I have tried collision algorithms many times
- Collision handling is done in the `canMoveHere` function and returns `true` or `false` to the `moveAll` function, where it is determined if the ball can move to the next square

---

My code on [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/b8j9yg47/)

---

My code download from [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7OJnVpBNrkDTXN3eVJLaVhpNk0)

---

My full code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <canvas id ="gameCanvas" width = "500" height = "500" style = "border:1px solid black;"></canvas>
    <script>
        var canvas, canvasContext;
        var framesPerSecond = 30;
        var gravity = .2;

        var leftKey = false;
        var rightKey = false;

        const TILE_H = 25;
        const TILE_W = 25;

        var map = [
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        ];

        var ball = {
            `x:250`,
            `y:250`,
            `radius:10`,
            color:"#ff9966",
            `velocityX:5`,
            `velocityY:1`,
            `terminalVel:8`,

            draw:function()
            {
                canvasContext.beginPath();
                canvasContext.fillStyle = this.color;
                canvasContext.arc(this.x, `this.y`, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
                canvasContext.fill();
                canvasContext.closePath();
            }
        };

        document.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt)
        {
            if(evt.keyCode == 37)
            {
                leftKey = true;
            }
            if(evt.keyCode == 39)
            {
                rightKey = true;
            }
        });

        document.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt)
        {
            if(evt.keyCode == 37)
            {
                leftKey = false;
            }
            if(evt.keyCode == 39)
            {
                rightKey = false;
            }
        });

        window.onload = function()
        {
            canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
            canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");

            setInterval(function()
            {
                drawAll();
                moveAll();
            }, 1000/framesPerSecond);
        }

        var renderMap = function()
        {
            for(var eachRow=0; eachRow<20; eachRow++)
            {
                for(var eachCol=0; eachCol<20; eachCol++)
                {
                    if(map[eachRow][eachCol] == 0)
                    {
                        canvasContext.fillStyle = "#a6a6a6";
                        canvasContext.fillRect(TILE_W*eachCol, TILE_H*eachRow, TILE_W, TILE_H);
                    }
                    if(map[eachRow][eachCol] == 1)
                    {
                        canvasContext.fillStyle = "#666666";
                        canvasContext.fillRect(TILE_W*eachCol, TILE_H*eachRow, TILE_W, TILE_H);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var drawAll = function()
        {
            canvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            renderMap();

            ball.draw();
        }

        var canMoveHere = function(col, row)
        {
            if(map[row][col] == 1)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        var moveAll = function()
        {
            nextBallX = `ball.x` + ball.velocityX;
            nextBallY = `ball.y` + ball.velocityY;
            nextBallCol = Math.floor(nextBallX / TILE_W);
            nextBallRow = Math.floor(nextBallY / TILE_H);
            var canMove = canMoveHere(nextBallCol, nextBallRow);

            ball.velocityY += gravity;
            `ball.y` += ball.velocityY;

            if(ball.velocityY >= ball.terminalVel)
            {
                ball.velocityY = ball.terminalVel;
            }

            if(canMove === false)
            {
                ball.velocityY *= -1;
            }

            if(leftKey)
            {
                `ball.x` -= ball.velocityX;
            }
            if(rightKey)
            {
                `ball.x` += ball.velocityX;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like the only step you're really missing is adjusting the position of the ball once the collision happens. You have the main bit of information you need to do that (the direction the ball is travelling in when the collision happens so you can work out which side of the block was collided with), so you just need to leverage that to say `ball.x = leftOrRightOfBlock` or `ball.y = topOrBottomOfBlock` inside your `if (!canMove) { }`.

Comment: How would I check if the ball hit it from the left or the right? I tried something like that before and it didn't work. It sounds like you're more knowledgeable about this than I am, can you try it on my code and post as an answer? When I tried I got the block's column by `var blockCol = Math.floor(ball.x / TILE_W);` and then checked if the ball's column is less then the block's column to tell if it was hit by the left.  As I said before, I couldn't get it to work, but maybe you can. @Marty

Answer (score 0):

You can't just say "if the ball can or cannot move over certain tile", you have to tell the game how to respond when an obstacle is hit and that depends on two factors: current ball direction and shape of the obstacle.

I modified your `canMoveHere` function to evaluate that:

```
var directionChange = function(nextCol, nextRow)
{
    var currentRow = Math.floor(ball.y / TILE_H);
    var currentCol = Math.floor(ball.x / TILE_W);
    var resultDirection = { x: 1, y: 1 };
    
    if (map[nextRow][nextCol] == 1) {
        if (map[nextRow][currentCol] == 1 && 
            map[currentRow][nextCol] == 0) { 
            // horizontal obstacle
            resultDirection.x = 1;
            resultDirection.y = -1;
        } else if (map[nextRow][currentCol] == 0 && 
                   map[currentRow][nextCol] == 1) { 
            // vertical obstacle
            resultDirection.x = -1;
            resultDirection.y = 1;
        } else { 
            // corner obstacle
            resultDirection.x = -1;
            resultDirection.y = -1;
        } 
    }            
    return resultDirection;
}
```

at this point we also modify the `moveAll` function accordingly

```
var moveAll = function()
{
    nextBallX = ball.x + ball.velocityX;
    nextBallY = ball.y + ball.velocityY;
    nextBallCol = Math.floor(nextBallX / TILE_W);
    nextBallRow = Math.floor(nextBallY / TILE_H);
    let dir = directionChange(nextBallCol, nextBallRow);
    ball.velocityY *= dir.y;
    ball.velocityX *= dir.x;

    ball.velocityY += gravity;
    if(ball.velocityY >= ball.terminalVel)
    {
        ball.velocityY = ball.terminalVel;
    }
    ball.y += ball.velocityY;

    if(leftKey) {
        ball.x -= ball.velocityX;
    }

    if(rightKey) {
        ball.x += ball.velocityX;
    }
}
```

Now you just have to find a way to let the keys drive the ball smoothly, because changing the velocity using positive/negative values has an effect to the actual direction of the ball, because it will go to the opposite direction of the pressed key when values are negatives;

I tried using absolute values

```
if(leftKey) {
    ball.x -= Math.abs(ball.velocityX);
}

if(rightKey) {
    ball.x += Math.abs(ball.velocityX);
}
```

but as soon as the ball hits an obstacle, the pressed key will keep pushing the ball against the obstacle changing again the velocity and - for how it is built now - the ball will go through the walls.

Even though this isn't a bug-free solution, I hope this can help you on solving the main problem.